# How to get Authorization token in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following ApiController that deals with Authorization via a before_action filter:

```
class ApiController < ApplicationController
  before_action :restrict_access

  private

  def restrict_access
    authenticate_or_request_with_http_token do |token, options|
      ApiKey.exists?(access_token: token)
    end
  end
end
```

This works fine.

Now, I have a controller from that Api that needs to use that ApiKey in order to find the associated user. So, I have tried doing this:

```
class OrdersController < ApiController
  def index
    # How do I access the ApiKey that has been detected in the parent filter?
    @user = ApiKey.find_by(access_token: params[:token]).user # This is not working
  end
end
```

This doesn't work because params[:token] is empty, because the token is passed in the Authorization header like `Authorization Token token='xxxx'`. So, how can I get that from my controller?

Comment: whats the error? and what does the model ApiKey look like?

Comment: The error is that params[:token] is empty because the parameter is passed through the Authorization HTTP header.

Comment: instead of params array , inspect `request.headers['Authorization']` and get the token from that collection. presumably `request.headers['Authorization']['token']`

Comment: There is no helpers in rails that let me get that directly? When inspecting request.headers['Authorization'] I see a simple string like this: '"Token token=\"3a1e581bd2603251ea2d7f2b1d5632e6\""'

Comment: you can extract the token with a pattern like `/(.*)=\"(.*)\"/.match(request.headers["Authorization"])[2]`  which is what i use

Comment: blotto, create an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to grab the token from `request.headers['Authorization']` use the following pattern

```
 /(.*)=\"(.*)\"/.match(request.headers["Authorization"])[2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple, you should look up your user IN the authenticate method, and set it to `@current_user` or whatnot.

Then you have it available in all requests and can just do:

```
class OrdersController < ApiController
  def index
    @current_user
  end
end
```

And your restrict_accees could be:

```
  def restrict_access
    authenticate_or_request_with_http_token do |token, options|
      user = ApiKey.where(access_token: token).includes(:user) #preloads user if available
      if user.present?
        @current_user = user
        true
      else 
        false
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: I don't even have an authenticate method?

Comment: within the restrict_access method i meant. :P